# Can't find /dev/disk/by-label/ANARCHYV100

Tags: usb-device

Today I wanted to install Anarchy. But there's a problem: It says:

> ```
> ERROR:  '/dev/disk/by-label/ANARCHYV100' device did not show up after 30 seconds...
> ```

In /dev/disk/ there's no by-label directory. I also tried flashing it on my USB with different programs on Linux (dd) and windows (etcher, win32diskimager, Rufus). I'm booting this stick over UEFI. I tried booting the official Arch Linux ISO [from](https://www.archlinux.org%20also,%20and%20the%20same%20error%20occurred%20but%20with%20the%20following%20path:%20/dev/disk/by-label/ARCH_201806). I also tried booting it over another USB port. Every time I get into an interactive shell.

Does anybody know a fix or is this a bug?

Comment: I think the iso file is buggy. I was able to boot from a USB pendrive cloned from the current iso file of Anarchy, but there were a few complaints during the boot, not only the one you describe. I arrived at the desktop, but the mouse and touchpad were dead on my Lenovo. Probably it works better in some other computer.

Comment: Nut if that would be the case, the Anarchy ISO and the official Arch ISO must be buggy. I tested it on my workstation, got the same error.

Comment: In my Toshiba laptop, the mouse works (and also the touchpad). And there, in BIOS mode, things seem to work better. There is also `/dev/disk/by-label/ANARCHYV100`. So I suggest that you try to boot in BIOS mode. Good luck :-)

Comment: The strange thing about it: About 3 months ago, I could boot into an arch iso on my laptop with uefi.

Comment: try to use balenaetcher, i have the same problem, the balena assing another name and works

Answer (score 0):

The installer expects the USB-drive under te auto-mount point

```
/dev/disk/by-label/ANARCHYV100
```

So rename your USB drive to `ANARCHYV100`, then try again the install.